# Android Studio Bumblebee problem with certificates

Tags: android-studio, ssl-certificate, pkix, android-studio-bumblebee

If I try to clean my Gradle cache, clean my project cache,
then I can't even **sync** my project in AS Bumblebee

*AS: Bumblebee | 2021.1.1; Kotlin plugin: 211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40; Android Gradle Plugin: 7.0.2; Gradle: 7.0.2; Gradle JDK: version 11.0.14; NDK: from local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found); LLDB: pinned revision 3.1 not found, latest from SDK: (package not found); CMake: from local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found), from PATH: (not found)*

because it throws out a problem with certificates:

> Starting Gradle Daemon... Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 79 ms
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'bitbucket'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools:r8:3.0.73.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools:r8:3.0.73.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/r8/3.0.73/r8-3.0.73.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/r8/3.0.73/r8-3.0.73.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools:r8:3.0.73.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/r8/3.0.73/r8-3.0.73.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/r8/3.0.73/r8-3.0.73.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools:r8:3.0.73.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/android/tools/r8/3.0.73/r8-3.0.73.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/android/tools/r8/3.0.73/r8-3.0.73.pom'.
> > > ���� ���� ���������� (nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom'.
> > > nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.7.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.7.1.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.7.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.7.1.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.7.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.7.1.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.7.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.7.1.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.7.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.7.1.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.7.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.7.1.pom'.
> > > nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.3.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.3.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/perf-plugin/1.3.3/perf-plugin-1.3.3.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/perf-plugin/1.3.3/perf-plugin-1.3.3.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.3.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/perf-plugin/1.3.3/perf-plugin-1.3.3.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/perf-plugin/1.3.3/perf-plugin-1.3.3.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.3.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/firebase/perf-plugin/1.3.3/perf-plugin-1.3.3.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/firebase/perf-plugin/1.3.3/perf-plugin-1.3.3.pom'.
> > > nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany
> > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany/repository/tband-maven-lib/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom'.
> > > nexus-ci.corp.dev.mycompany
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > Required by:
> > project : > com.malinskiy.marathon:marathon-gradle-plugin:0.6.3
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the
> > client to allow other protocols to be used. See:
> > https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> > find valid certification path to requested target
> > > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
>
> ...
> ...
>
> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:170)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:150)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:135)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:105)
> ... 239 more
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 38s

It's all strange, because I can open links in browser
and see all that *.pom files

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it was our internal problem.

I browsed problematic urls in Chrome,
then pressed on a 'lock' icon left to url address,
watched what certificate is used...

Then exported this certificate into file
and added to java 'cacerts' file (for example `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\lib\security\cacerts`) with KeyStore Explorer

So my problems with SSL certificate were resolved